# Android, check alpha of pixel?

Tags: android

I get the colour of my bitmap under the touch x and y:

```
int myX = (int)event.getX();
int myY = (int)event.getY();
int color = pngTestBM.getPixel(myX,myY);
```

How can I check if the pixel is transparent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you are:

```
int alpha = Color.alpha(pixel);
```

Answer (score 8):

What about [alpha](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#alpha%28int%29) method of Color class?

```
int transparency = Color.alpha(color);
```

Answer (score 7):

The `color` is a 32 bit ARGB value, and a *completely* opaque pixel has an Alpha value of 0xff whilst a completely transparent pixel has an alpha value of 0x00.

Assuming you just want to find out if it is completely transparent you can just do:

```
int color = pngTestBM.getPixel(myX, myY);
boolean transparent = (color & 0xff000000) == 0x0;
```

Comment: This always returns true for each and every pixel of my image.